# Bitcoin core HD wallet: how sensitive is the 'hdmasterkeyid' ?

Tags: bitcoind, bitcoin-core, bip32-hd-wallets

I have recently upgraded my `bitcoind` node to `v0.13.0` and encrypted a new HD wallet:

```
$ bitcoin-cli getwalletinfo
```

I am getting some `hdmasterkeyid` hexadecimal number displayed on the screen. I have not yet done my homework on HD wallets and reading the relevant sections of 'Mastering Bitcoin' does not alleviate my fear: should I be worried about `hdmasterkeyid` being displayed on my screen? how sensitive is this number? I am guessing this is safe (as no password authentication is required to get this number) but I would like to make sure this is the case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not sensitive at all.

In particular, it does not allow people to derive addresses, does not allow them to recognize addresses that are yours, and cannot be used to infer anything about your private keys.